# Onmouseout event not working

Tags: javascript, event, outputlink

I'm trying to show an iframe **onmouseover** event and close that iframe **onmouseout**. Onmouseover is working but not the **onmouseout** event. Here's what I have tried....

```
<apex:outputLink value="OrderTrackingClass?id={!o.id}" 
                 onmouseover="var awin=window.open('OrderLines?id={!o.id}','Order Lines','height=300, width=1000, left=400, scrollbars=yes');"
                 onmouseout="awin.close();">
    {!o.Orders__c}
</apex:outputLink>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console errors?

Comment: The `onmouseover` event creates the `awin` variable which may not be visible by the `onmouseout` event. Try doing something like `onmouseout="alert(awin);"` to see what `awin` is in the `onmouseout` event.

Comment: Thanks! Just checked it says ReferenceError: awin is not defined.

Comment: @BarCotter On trying onmouseout="alert(awin);" nothing happens the iframe remains open

Comment: It wasn't a solution to fix your issue, it was only a way of getting the `awin` variable displayed in the alert box which would highlight the issue that it is an unknown variable

Comment: Yes I understand. I meant to say that the alert box doesn't show up :)

Comment: I removed var and it started working!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a blind guess! I removed the keyword **var** and the **onmouseout** started working!

```
  <apex:outputLink value="OrderTrackingClass?id={!o.id}" 
             onmouseover="awin=window.open('OrderLines?id={!o.id}','Order Lines','height=300, width=1000, left=400, scrollbars=yes');"
             onmouseout="awin.close();">
{!o.Orders__c}
```

</apex:outputLink>

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think var is creating a private variable which is unknown to the onmouseout call. Removing var making the awin variable to available in global scope. So that onmouseout it's getting awin variable and closing it.